# Почему на разных устройствах анимация работает по-разному в одном браузере?

Tags: css, css-animation, crossbrowsertesting

Ссылка на codepen с полным кодом данного элемента: https://codepen.io/VladimirR04/pen/YzjyxyK

```
.carr__card {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #442222;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
 top: 35px;
 left: 125px;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 text-align: center;
 animation-name: slider;
 -webkit-animation-name: slider;
 -moz-animation-name: slider;
 animation-duration: 24s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 24s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 24s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
```

В Chrome на iOS отображается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На android тоже в Chrome:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл проблему, но не знаю как её решить, свойство perspective не работает на android chrome browser, можете подсказать чем заменить?

Comment: Укажите версию Chrome с обоих устройств.

Comment: а что именно отличается?

Comment: @NNL993 на android 111.0.5563.57, на iOS тоже самое, только последние 2 цифры 72

Comment: @Grundy на ios картинки плавно приближаются и отдаляются, а на android это просто полоска картинок на половину смещённая в сторону, которая мигает ими в произвольном порядке

Comment: @ВладимирРоманенко думаю просто мобильные браузеры не поддерживают translateZ. Также если что они не поддерживают стиль flex-direction: column-reverse; - именно reverse))

Comment: Поэтому нужно решать это пробовать решать с помощью scale может быть?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи [`translateZ`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ#browser_compatibility), [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#browser_compatibility).

Comment: @ΝNL993 Я лишь предположил, так как именно он отвечает за выпячивание. Пусть пробует убрать translateZ и если в десктопе будет также как в мобильной, а в мобильной не будет изменений, значит это он.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что один и тот же браузер на РАЗНЫХ операционках - это реально одинаковые браузеры?

Comment: @Инквизитор поддержка элементов в мобильном браузере от одного производителя же не должна отличатся в зависимости от того айфон у тебя или самсунг, это супер не логично

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи убрал translateZ, анимация прокрутки и приближения пропала и на десктопе и на мобильном, но на мобильном оно ещё начало переключаться не по duration, а раз в долю секунды, странный результат

Comment: Проблему нашёл в свойстве perspective, если его закоментить, то на десктопе будет то же, что и на андроиде в браузере, не знаю чем его заменить вообще можно

Comment: @ВладимирРоманенко, если б вы знали, как происходит разработка ПО, не удивлялись бы =) браузер-то один, но на разных платформах по сути это разные продукты, делаемые разными людьми. в виндовой версии сделали, в андроидной еще не сделали, в айфонной сделали, но с багом, в макосьной  вообще не собирались.